# Conditional creation of closures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

Say I have a function like this:

```
function wrap_function(fnInput)
{
    if (somecondition)
    {
        return function() { 

            // Simplified example, in reality doing more stuff in here
            fnInput.apply(this, arguments)

        }
    }
    else
    {
        return fnInput;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that if `somecondition` is false this function *won't* create a closure and therefore won't have performance/memory impacts associated with closures.

Is this correct?

Comment: The "performance/memory impacts" of a closure in this case is absolutely minimal. If *somecondition* is true, the activation object created when *wrap_function* is called stays on the scope chain of the anonymous function, but might be optimised away since no use is made of it. *fnInput* might be a direct reference to the original (function?) object passed to *wrap_function*. In the worst case, there is only one extra lookup when resolving the identifier *fnInput* inside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `somecondition` is false a closure will not be created.  You're using the loosely typed nature of javascript in your example

Comment: Thanks... that's what I thought, just needed to be sure.